# Segoe UI Symbol 5.9 on Windows 7

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-7, windows-8, fonts

I would like to use Segoe UI Symbol fonts, as described:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx

to provide icons for an application.  This is a WPF application that will be deployed to Windows 7 and potentially 8. Windows 7 machines do not appear to have the same version of this font (5.0 vs. 5.9).  I found a knowledge base article that claims to inject some of the missing things:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094

But I still seem to be missing most or all of what is described at the first link.  Is there a way to get a Windows-8-compatible version of Segoe UI Symbol on Windows 7 machines?  This is a controlled-deployment environment so we can make needed configuration changes on the target machines.

Comment: Home page [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1798).  Purchase links don't work well though, try phone or email.

Comment: I had already been there.  If you follow the purchase links you eventually get to Ascender, and they don't seem to have Segoe UI Symbol.  I have contacted them for information, but this should be something Microsoft is solving for all Windows 7 systems, in my opinion.

Comment: In my opinion, SO question askers should properly document their research.  But that's an opinion, it has very little to do with reality.

Comment: Hans, I appreciate the time you have taken to try and help, but the site that you referenced does not appear to offer the product in question.  I am not sure how that is my fault.  I find if I put everything I have done already in the question, it is less likely to get answered.  It also tends to "poison the well".

Comment: I received confirmation from Ascender that they do no offer this font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally found a way to use the newer version of "Segoe UI Symbol" even when older version is installed (i.e. on Windows 7). The idea is to create a copy of the font file with a different name. This approach works also in ClickOnce installation and requires no bootstrapping.

It is posted on this link: [Embedded Font in WPF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893433/embedded-font-in-wpf-not-working/27911618)